# Windows keeps issuing a "computer needs repair at boot"

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

First of all, the PC boots up and I can access Ubuntu.

But there is smth very strange. When I boot I receive a windows alert saying:

**Your PC needs repair** and an error like 0x00000000F or so.

It gives me some options and if I press Esc and then access the Boot Loader, I can load Ubuntu.

I have tried with sudo efibootmgr removing windows, and checking it is actually removed.

But then at restart the same alert happens. Any ideas how to solve this?

It is not dual boot, I removed Windows and Installed Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Do ypu know if you are using UEFI booting or legacy boot mode? My guess is you sre using the latter but the mbr has not been upgraded. My bet is you need to install grub to the mbr (and maybe toggle the boot partition to active). Assumong your boot disk is sda, you can write grub to mbr from Ubuntu  with **sudo grub-install /dev/sda**   (Let us know if that works..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Ubuntu install went well for the most part, but there's something slightly off with how the boot device was set up.

Can you share a photo of the screen you see?  You can see some examples here: https://www.4winkey.com/windows-10/how-to-fix-your-pc-needs-to-be-repaired-error-on-windows-10.html

Before you go start to go through the troubleshooting steps there, note that the goal for those steps is likely going to be to get Windows working, and it sounds like that isn't your intention.

My guess is that you may end up needing to make some BIOS changes to ensure the Ubuntu bootloader (GRUB, probably?) is started at boot.  It seems like there may be the smallest portion of a Windows bootloader lying around somewhere left over, possibly from a recovery partition or the like, and it seems like the BIOS is trying to boot that instead.

Because you can access your desired OS with a workaround (as you mentioned, this isn't critical, but it would be good to fix it to make your life easier.

Since you're messing around with how your computer starts up, I suggest making sure you have an Ubuntu live-cd (or equivalent) handy, just in case, and copy down all of the current BIOS settings into a notebook so that you can restore them if one of the changes doesn't work out the way you would like.  It would be a good time to take a backup of your important data also, just in case.